# How to get font information in Adobe pagemaker 7.0 p65 file export to HTML?

Tags: html, fonts, adobe

I have some files which are in p65 format, there are lots of such file. I am exporting all such file in html and parsing with my script. But suddenly i realize it is not returning font information. I don't want all font info. as such but symbol font in particular i want. Otherwise it shows simple character instead of symbol. I know p65 is old format and now indesign is supported but. Is there any way i can get html with font info from  Adobe pagemaker 7.0  p65 file?

Answer (score 1):

PMD is depreciated file format of Adobe. The last patch was released on 9 July 2001 as per wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_PageMaker. Using Adobe PageMaker 7.0, it's not possible to access the font information. Better, you try out something using Adobe ID CS6.

Comment: I know it is depreciated file format of Adobe. But that doesn't mean it is not possible to extract such information which exist in it. I found some solution to extract font info. from Adobe PageMaker 7.0. But still looking for full fledge solution.